# How to understand the difference between LXD and VM and Docker?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, virtual-machine, travis-ci, lxd

When I am using Travis-CI, I need to choose between LXD and full VM: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/. Although the linked page describes their features in specific usages, I would like to ask how conceptually LXD differs from so-called full VM, and how do they compare with Docker? I would assume that a CI test should run on a server with Linux or other OS pre-installed and that we do not need to run a LXD or VM on the server side. So I am quite confused with the basic concepts of LXD or VM run on a server. Any clarification?